# Copy column from 1 workbook to another apart from the header row(first row)

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I've been trying to copy the entire column from workbook1 to workbook2 but not include the first row. How do I copy over the first row and save the result to a new workbook (workbook3).

I've got the following code so far

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb1 = load_workbook("test1.xlsx")
wb2 = load_workbook("test2.xlsx")

ws1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
ws2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

for i in range(1, mr + 1):
        ws2['A' + str(i)].value = ws1['A' + str(i)].value
       wb2.save("test1.xlsx")
        wb1.save("test2.xlsx")
```

Comment: Can you not just open the new work book and use the cell accesses the copy it over? I’m not really sure what problem you’re having here?

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence seems clear;
*I've been trying to copy the entire column from workbook1 to workbook2 but not include the first row.* 

Then your second sentence is somewhat different;
*How do I copy over the first row and save the result to a new workbook (workbook3).*
Is the second sentence a separate question in addition to the first?

For the first sentence/question which your code appears to cover; Copy a column excluding the first row is easy enough. Just `continue` on row 1 and copy the rest as you have.

There are some changes I have made to your code as the the syntax is depreciated or has other preferred method.

Note also;

1. You only need to save a file that was changed. The Excel file 'test1.xlsx' is being read from so it has not been changed and doesn't need to be saved
2. wb2, the workbook that was changed, was opened from `'test2.xlsx'`. You are saving it as the origin workbook `'test1.xlsx'` which would overwrite the original file.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb1 = load_workbook("test1.xlsx")
wb2 = load_workbook("test2.xlsx")

ws1 = wb1['Sheet1']  # get_sheet_by_name is depreciated use this method instead
ws2 = wb2['Sheet1']

mr = ws1.max_row
# mc = ws1.max_column  # Not used

for i in range(1, mr + 1):
    if i == 1:
        continue
    # ws2['A' + str(i)].value = ws1['A' + str(i)].value
    ### Use f strings, no need to cast
    ws2[f'A{i}'].value = ws1[f'A{i}'].value  # Copy row to row
    # ws2[f'A{i-1}'].value = ws1[f'A{i}'].value  # Copy to row 1 onwards on the destination sheet


### Only need to save the workbook once after all changes are complete, 
### not every time a change is made so this should not be in the loop
# wb2.save("test1.xlsx")  # Overwriting the original workbook???
wb2.save("test2.xlsx")
# wb1.save("test2.xlsx")  # Why save this workbook? Also wrong file name
```

If sentence 2 is a separate question and you want to copy just the row 1 effectively cell A1, you can do the same as before but needs no loop. Just create a new workbook then copy origin cell `A1` to cell new `A1` and save as the workbook name `workbook3`.